# Gender and "Seeding" - Just Torah-Derived or Common Belief?

Tags: history, sexuality, science, maseches-niddah

[Niddah 31a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Niddah.31a.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes (Davidson Edition translation):

> אמר רבי יצחק אמר רבי אמי אשה מזרעת תחילה יולדת זכר איש מזריע תחילה יולדת נקבה שנאמר (ויקרא יב, ב) אשה כי תזריע וילדה זכר
>
> Rabbi Yitzḥak says that Rabbi Ami says: The sex of a fetus is determined at the moment of conception. If the woman emits seed first, she gives birth to a male, and if the man emits seed first, she gives birth to a female, as it is stated: “If a woman bears seed and gives birth to a male” (Leviticus 12:2).

Was this simply something that the Rabbis derived from the above verse, or was it also a common belief at the time? Is it found in contemporary or earlier "scientific" works?

This would have ramifications on what they might mean by this statement (and perhaps how it should be viewed from the perspective of believing it).

Comment: I thought we had this question (or at least a closely related one) but cannot now find it.

Comment: https://journals.openedition.org/cliowgh/339

Comment: Should we ask the meaning of אשה מזרעת first?

Comment: A very interesting article on ancient scientific beliefs: https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/discovery-where-babies-come-from

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya,_Vayikra.12.2.6

Comment: @dr thanks, interesting read

Comment: For some animals it's true.

Answer (score 1):

[Ramban on that pasuk](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.12.2?with=Ramban&lang=bi&aliyot=0) seems to bring the knowledge of doctors and the philosophy of the Greeks agreeing with this idea.

> כי תזריע וילדה לרבות ילדתו מחוי שנמחה ונעשה כעין זרע אמו טמאה לידה ופירוש הענין שנוצר הולד בצורת אדם ואחר כך נמוח שכל מי שאין בו מצורת אדם אינו ולד וכל מי שאינו ראוי לברית נשמה אינו ולד אבל בשעת הלידה אפילו מחוי מטמא אם אנו מכירין צורתו כגון שפיר מרוקם טמאה ודאי ואם לאו בספק וזהו רבוי של מקרא זה כדברי רבותינו (נדה כז) ובמשמעותו אמרו (שם לא) אשה כי תזריע אשה מזרעת תחילה יולדת זכר ואין כוונתם שיעשה הולד מזרע האשה כי האשה אע"פ שיש לה ביצים כביצי זכר או שלא יעשה בהן זרע כלל או שאין הזרע ההוא נקפא ולא עושה דבר בעובר אבל אמרם "מזרעת" על דם הרחם שיתאסף בשעת גמר ביאה באם ומתאחז בזרע הזכר כי לדעתם הולד נוצר מדם הנקבה ומלובן האיש ולשניהם יקראו זרע וכך אמרו (שם) שלשה שותפין יש בו באדם איש מזריע בו לובן שממנו גידים ועצמות ולובן שבעין אשה מזרעת אודם שממנו עור ובשר ודם ושער ושחור שבעין **וגם דעת הרופאים ביצירה כך היא ועל דעת פילוסופי היונים** כל גוף העובר מדם האשה אין בו לאיש אלא הכח הידוע בלשונם היולי שהוא נותן צורה בחומר כי אין בין ביצת התרנגולת הבאה מן הזכר לנולדת מן המתפלשת בעפר שום הפרש וזו תגדל אפרוח וזו לא תזרע ולא תצמיח בהמנע ממנה החום היסודי שהוא לה היולי ואם כן יהיה מלת תזריע כמו זרועיה תצמיח (ישעיהו סא יא) וכן אמר אונקלוס ארי תעדי "דותה" - לשון דבר הזב מגופה ד"א לשון מדוה וחולי שאין אשה רואה דם שלא תחלה וראשה ואיבריה כבדין עליה לשון רש"י ולא ידעתי מאיזה מוצא יהיה דותה לשון דבר הזב בלשון הקודש אבל יתכן שיהיה לשון מדוה ממה שאמרו (נדה ט) וראשה ואבריה כבדין עליה וכן דעת רבי אברהם שאומר כי דותה שם וטעמו חולי כי הדם היוצא חולי באשה ובאמת שהוא ניקוי המותרות ומפני שראשה ואבריה כבדין עליה אולי יקרא חולי והנכון לשון מדוה שהוא כמו נגע וצער כמו עלי לבי דוי (ירמיהו ח יח) היה דוה לבנו (איכה ה יז) כמו נגע לבבו (מלכים א ח לח) והנה הזיבה נגע באשה אע"פ שהיא בתולדתה וכן על ערש דוי (תהלים מא ד)

Comment: T’was an old Greek *machlokes* :) See [this](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2031/No.%201/The%20Rabbinic%20Conception.pdf) article.

Comment: Ramban is referring to the makeup of the fetus, not that if a woman is "mazria" first (whatever that means) a male is born. I asked about the latter. -1

Comment: Read the whole piece. He ties the two ideas together. @רבות

Comment: @user6951 just because Ramban did, that doesn't mean that they (doctors and Greeks) did as well. It's simply him trying to explain chazal according to the science of his times...

Comment: Which is why I wrote that Ramban brings etc. It was presented as his perception. @רבות

Comment: @user6951 I would say that Ramban explains this based on principles of the doctors of his time and Greek philosophers, not that they agree with this idea.

Comment: He wrote vigam daas etc. I don't see your translation any more or less accurate than mine. He also didn't say which doctors he was referring to or how long they had that idea for, 10 years or one thousand. Certainly his claim that the Greeks discussed it answers your question 'Is it found in any contemporary or earlier scientific works.' The answer is yes, the Ramban says the Greek philosophers had that idea.  @רבות

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96583/discussion-between---and-user6591).

Comment: Sorry, but I think it is irrelevant to cite Ramban that lived 1000 years after the Talmud to show what Rabbis knew about human anatomy.