Can we compare הוצאת זרע לבטלה to abortion?
We know that הוצאת זרע לבטלה is forbidden (e.g. .נדה יג). Would having an abortion be different than this? If yes, why? Is this comparison brought down anywhere?
Disclaimer: I'm only asking about this specific comparison - I know the question of abortion has been asked here before. Also, I am talking about the general concept of abortion, I understand that there are still exceptions that allow women to get one.

+1 although I reckon you can do better by explaining why you think they are similar more explicitly

עיין נשנת אהלות ז׳ ב׳

AFAIK, the sages were unaware of the existence of the eggs and the process of fertilization. The fetus was considered a direct development of the semen inside the womb. So in some sense, to their level of understanding, those two are comparable.

@RabbiKaii see my comment

@AlBerko incorrect the gemarra says the woman and the man are מזריע

Chavos yair 31 makes this argument

Are you asking if abortion could be less problematic?

@DoubleAA answer!

As @DoubleAA noted, Chavos Yair classifies abortion as hotzaas zera levatalah, and Tzitz Eliezer ruled like this (requiring a female Jewish doctor in situations of necessary abortion)

@robev Sources?

@AlBerko https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105845/759

@robev I remember now the question I commented, nothing here implies the fertilization of the egg. Please read Ramban's answer (13th century!): ובמשמעותו אמרו (שם לא) אשה כי תזריע אשה מזרעת תחילה יולדת זכר ואין כוונתם שיעשה הולד מזרע האשה כי האשה אע"פ שיש לה ביצים כביצי זכר או שלא יעשה בהן זרע כלל או שאין הזרע ההוא נקפא ולא עושה דבר בעובר. אבל אמרם "מזרעת" על דם הרחם שיתאסף בשעת גמר ביאה באם ומתאחז בזרע הזכר כי לדעתם הולד נוצר מדם הנקבה ומלובן האיש ולשניהם יקראו זרע.
So I was right.

@DoubleAA Is his opinion not widely accepted? I don't know much about him but I find it interesting that this comparison isn't more prevalent in the abortion debate.

@Rardal not sure anything about abortion is widely accepted

@DoubleAA true, I meant his opinion in a broad sense, not in this specific case. Happens to be I found this document from Rav Lichtenstein who says that it may be that it is only wasting if wasted at the moment of emission, although he seems to be unsure to make it a set in stone claim. see pg. 4: https://traditiononline.org/abortion-a-halakhic-perspective/

@Rardal The chavos yair's position is difficult since it's generally assumed normal intercourse with ones menopausal/pregnant/infertile spouse is not considered a waste. If so, this shouldn't be worse since neither ends up with children.

@DoubleAA True, but that would depend on the reasons it is not considered waste in those instances. Do you know why/has that been asked here before?

They are totally different because abortion is a question of pikuach nefesh.

@Shimshon I noted in the disclaimer that I’m not talking about cases where one has an exception to have an abortion.

@Rardal so she’s having an abortion on a whim? I don’t understand the hypothetical.

@Shimshon you can't think of any cases of abortion where one does not have an exception to have one? Do you believe abortion is always allowed no matter what?

@Rardal I am not an expert
